# Per Pixel Alpha Blend

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap

For quite sometime now I have been trying to accomplish some sort of form which allows transparency with PNG images.

I am working in C# and I was able to find a nice project that achieved this via per pixel alpha blend and by changing the image to a bitmap and using an alpha layer to only show parts which aren't transparent, which is then updated with UpdateLayeredWindow.

Here is the project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1822/Per-Pixel-Alpha-Blend-in-C

I was able to implement the code from the aforementioned project but due to the create parameters which is set the form is basically made invisible and only the image is shown. And when I remove the create parameters the effect is not applied.

But I am wanting to be able to apply this to my form background. For my form I have set the form border style to none and applied a background image.

**How can I apply this technique to my form background and still be able to add controls which will not be affected?**

Comment: I'm confused. Doesn't PNG offer built-in support for transparency?

Comment: Afaik, layered windows are just bitmaps drawn with alpha channel on the screen. Any controls have to be customly drawn to this bitmap. If you have solid sections in the bitmap, you're better to go with a non-layered "content" form over the layered one, moving with it. The content form can have controls like any other. Example here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20758/Alpha-Blended-Windows-Forms

Comment: Yes but when using a background image for forms the transparency on PNG images are disregarded, hence the usage of transparency keys, which is ugly.

Comment: I know that, you have no other choice than layered windows to have an alpha channel form. But this comes with the disadvantage of controls not being usable with it. Have a look at my edit of my first comment to combine both worlds of layered windows and control-compatible windows.

Comment: Should this be tagged `windows-forms`? It's not clear.

Comment: @heltonbiker: I'd bet so. He linked to a WinForms tutorial and from his responses to my answer, it's very clear he's using WinForms.

Comment: @FarboD don't forget to accept an answer if it helped^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the technique of layered windows to be able to have a background with alpha-transparency. This comes with the disadvantage of not being able to *see* controls on it. That's because the layered window is just an image. If you put controls on it, you will still get their events and messages, but to actually *see* them, you would have to draw all the controls on this bitmap and keep it up to date with the controls state. Tedious.

There's no other way to get an alpha-form though (at least not a good one I'm aware of).

If you're just caring about an alpha-transparent *border* of the form, and the client / inner part of the form being solid, you should think about creating a second "content" form, above the layered window which makes up the border, and move it with the layered window. Thus, you can combine the best of both worlds.

An example is seen here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20758/Alpha-Blended-Windows-Forms.
It also discusses typical traps when implementing such 2-form-fashion and how to avoid them.

Afaik, Office 2013 and VS 2013 do it in a similar fashion (with WPF-like powered drawing though), notice all the nice bugs their window shadow has.

Another choice, if you can choose it: Use WPF. Since the control drawing is completely rendered by your graphics card which renders it to a single graphics buffer, it can turn such buffer into the bitmap of a layered window and thus keep it up to date with the controls perfectly. I've never done that though since I'm not a WPF programmer, but I've seen this in action and bet there are some nice commenters giving links to good tutorials.

Comment: Okay, so I thought this would be the best way of going about it, so I have my layered window form and my normal window, but now the problem is how do I make the backcolour of my normal window transparent so that it can be see through, allowing me to see my layered window.

Comment: You cannot make it see through. As said, it will be opaque. Of course, this is only useful if the transition to the layered window will be seamless. E.g., imagine a layered window having a glassy border, and the glassy borders fade into black to the inside. Then you can make a solid form with an *opaque* black background, and noone will see that are two forms. You won't be able to see your layered window through your content form, never, sorry (I didn't made that! ;D). Only a transparency key would be a chance for the content window. Can I see an image of what your form should look like?

Comment: I did some research and I found that transparency key is the best option, I tried setting it in the form properties but it wasn't working. I tried it via code and it worked fine, so now I have a seamless layered window and another window on top of it which I have linked the position to the main form and is updated every time the main window moves. Though at the moment, I have set my second form to topmost, is there a way to make it appear only on top of my main form?

Comment: Looking at the linked tutorial, he discusses that under "Getting Mouse Input".

Comment: *This comes with the disadvantage of not being able to use controls on it*. This is not true (partially). You can have all the controls and get all the messages normally **but** as you said *You would have to draw all the controls on this bitmap...*

Comment: Yes, that's actually a "more correct" statement. I edit my answer.