# C# Transparent Form Drops Pixels With Antialiasing

Tags: c#

I'm trying to draw on screen with a "top-most" and "transparent" form. But when i enable the anti-aliasing it drops pixels.

[image: Application screenshot]

I'm using Microsoft.Ink.dll also i use this code for transparent form:

```
this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
```

Comment: There are other ways, what you tried is legacy winforms. You can do it with winforms, but if you don't need controls on your transparent form take a look at alpha blending PNG's, I recently used it for a video overlay.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871869/per-pixel-alpha-blend

Comment: That is how TransparencyKey  works. Winforms is not made for glitz.